# How to manage multiple versions of documentation with Sphinx?

Tags: c++, versioning, python-sphinx

I maintain a small library project written in C++.
I'd like to use Sphinx to maintain the library website + user documentation per release version. I have found [similar question asked [How to manage many versions?](https://groups.google.com/group/sphinx-dev/browse_thread/thread/fb8ba5cfa890b587/) on the [sphinx-dev](https://groups.google.com/group/sphinx-dev/) mailing list [which I have bumped](https://groups.google.com/group/sphinx-dev/browse_thread/thread/d907b2447e073cea) but without extensive follow-up.

How to manage many versions?

I think of basic structure like this:

```
mylib/     <- website root
mylib/...
mylib/tutorial/...
mylib/doc   <- list of documentation per release version
mylib/doc/1.0.0
mylib/doc/2.0.0
mylib/doc/X.Y.Z
```

I'm trying to figure out best practical configuration for this structure.
I have root configuration `mylib/conf.py` where I control the website structure and content.

I could put .rst files into `mylib/doc/1.0.0` and `mylib/doc/2.0.0` build them using the root conf.py. But then it seems tricky to control toctree for website and for docs.

So, I think it may be more practical to separate website config/build from per release documentation config/builds:

```
mylib/conf.py
mylib/doc/1.0.0/conf.py
mylib/doc/2.0.0/conf.py
mylib/doc/X.Y.Z/conf.py
```

but I'd like the main documents in `mylib/doc/X.Y.Z/conf.py` to use the same layout is the root documents in `mylib/`, so I can have consistent look, e.g. links in page header, etc.

This way I can easily achieve consistent `toctree` per documentation release.
It  should be easy to walk the directories and perform builds for website and for each doc version separately.

Regarding searching the documentation, I don't mind the search engine to scan all versions of documentation per single query as well as I don't mind to have search engine specific to particular version (search box is displayed in the same place, but depending what is being read, it scans index of current version only).

Is there any better way to achieve that?

I've found similar question asked in [sphinx for multiple, separate documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836080/sphinx-for-multiple-separate-documents) and I'm wondering if the [Intersphinx plugin](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/intersphinx.html) is a good idea here.

UPDATE:

- 2017-04-10: SO answer pointing to an interesting Sphinx extension: [sphinxcobtrib-versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38927796/151641)
- 2011-10-21: Following [olt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19759/olt)'s question in comments, `mylib/` is not how I mean to structure project in VCS. So, I don't want to maintain multiple versions of documentation in VCS. The `mylib/` is just structure for easier visualisation. It can be also working directory where I put Sphinx sources together (e.g. pull from version branches, etc.) and where I launch Sphinx to build the output.

Comment: Do you really need the source of the documentation for all releases? You do have version control for that.

Comment: @olt I see 'mylib' may be confusing. I don't assume this is how I have project structured in VCS. I assume source of doc is in tag/branch in VCS. Then I can pull everything into mylib/ before I want to run Sphinx build to generate whole documentation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334392/combining-sphinx-documentation-from-multiple-subprojects-handling-indices-sync describes some approaches to managing common conf.py settings

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the documentation should stay with the code in the same repository. Otherwise you would need to manage the documentation source manually, for example when you backport a feature from version B to A. With a single repository, you just check out that version and re-build the documentation.

You should look at [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/) project, they have multiple versions of their documentation available on the same site. The documentation is in the same repository and they [copy the output](http://hg.sqlalchemy.org/sqlalchemyorg/file/7b12fe891c00/site/_config.py.SAMPLE#l16) of each version into their static homepage folders.

Comment: I had a brief conversation with @mloskot in Twitter. Added my answer here for the record.