# How do I have multiple versions of my doc with sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx

Like the documentation of python or django, how do I have multiple versions of my doc with sphinx ?

I saved my doc on git, and I want my user to be able to see documentation for different version like `v2.7`,`v3.4`, etc

Thank you for the help

Comment: Do you want a drop-down list where the version can be selected, such as in the upper left corner of https://docs.python.org/2/?

Comment: @mzjn exactly what I want

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850093/how-to-manage-multiple-versions-of-documentation-with-sphinx/7860481

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could just use Read The Docs to host your documentation for you. They automatically handle multiple versions with a dropdown:
https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

If you'd like to host your own documentation on GitHub Pages or some other web server, I made a Sphinx extension that does what you're looking for:
https://github.com/sphinx-contrib/sphinxcontrib-versioning

Comment: ReadTheDocs only seems to offer users two versions: `stable` and `latest` (which is 
a pointer to the most recently tagged version). This doesn't really address the OPs requirement, which is to make an arbitrary number of versions available.

Comment: i believe readthedocs lets you add your own versions in their UI

Answer (score 18):

There's the [sphinx-multiversion](https://holzhaus.github.io/sphinx-multiversion/) extension.

It's similar to sphinxcontrib-versioning, but sphinxcontrib-versioning doesn't seem to be actively maintained. The last release was in 2016, and it doesn't work with more recent versions of Sphinx ([issue #77](https://github.com/sphinx-contrib/sphinxcontrib-versioning/issues/77)). sphinx-multiversion is a new implementation (see [comment by the author](https://github.com/sphinx-contrib/sphinxcontrib-versioning/pull/78#issuecomment-599193860)).

Note on healthiness of the project: as of December 2020, it seems that SMV is a one-person project and there are a number of open issues and pull requests that haven't been responded to (though see [this comment by the author](https://github.com/sphinx-contrib/sphinxcontrib-versioning/issues/77#issuecomment-737481668)).

Comment: How do I actually test this extension locally. I have installed the multiversion extension, I wanted to know how I can see the different version of the document in the HTML.